# Objective-C unicode to utf8

Tags: objective-c, unicode, encoding, utf-8, air-native-extension

I have a NSString in objective-c with unicode encoding and I want to convert it to UTF8.
Looks simple but I cannot find a simple way to do it, and there's not so much info on the web.

Basically Im using FRE to send objects to AS3 and I have problems with the encoding. The problem is related to special characters that don't appear on AS3 side.

EDIT:

This is my main problem, I have this name in a NSString Stanisław. And this is the result from a extended method in NSString:

```
NSLog(@"%@, %d, %s", self, [self length], [self UTF8String]);

//Result: Stanisław, 9, Stanis≈Çaw
```

So when I move the UTF8String to AS3 I obtain a different name (Basically the result is Stanisła (without the last letter)

The method Im using to convert strings to FRE objects is:

```
uint32_t st = FRENewObjectFromUTF8([self length], (const uint8_t *)[self UTF8String], &rv);
```

Comment: utf8 is *a* unicode encoding, along with utf16 and utf32. which one do you have in the original>

Comment: oh thanks, Im not sure, but Im going to check which one Im using on each side (obj-c and AS3)

Comment: It is unclear what you want, please provide more usage information and code if possible.

Comment: I added some comments and code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in

```
uint32_t st = FRENewObjectFromUTF8([self length], (const uint8_t *)[self UTF8String], &rv);
```

is that `[self length]` is the number of Unicode characters in the string, and not the
number of UTF-8 bytes in `[self UTF8String]`.

In your case `"Stanisław"` has **9** Unicode characters which are converted to **10** UTF-8 bytes.
Your code would send only the first 9 bytes, which is the "shortening" that you 
observed.

Therefore you should replace your code with

```
const char *utf8 = [self UTF8String];
uint32_t st = FRENewObjectFromUTF8(strlen(utf8), (const uint8_t *)utf8, &rv);
```

Comment: Yes, I did it and now works fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the UTF8 representation of any NSString by sending it a `-UTF8String` message.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea, note than likely what is wanted is a data representation such as `dataUsingEncoding:`. In particular the docs for `UTF8String` state: "you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you called this method". The lifetime is not guaranteed.

Comment: Love you profile tag: "Available for your projects at great expense and inconvenience!", I may steal it!

Comment: I added some comments and code, probably that can clarify my main problem

Answer (score 0):

And if you have a `NSString`, you can just do

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Or, if you needed a `const char *` (which is unlikely), you could use:

```
const char *anotherString = [string UTF8String];
```

---

Now, if this `NSString` is something you originally retrieved from your server in the form of a `NSData`, you'd convert it from the `NSData` you got from your network request to a string with something like:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

In this case, though, you'd have to confirm what you mean by the fact that the server used "unicode encoding". That is ambiguous, and you have to confirm if it's UTF8 (which is what I used above), or UTF16 (and if UTF16, which one, e.g. `NSUTF16StringEncoding` or `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding` or ...) or whatever.